# The induction proof in Isabelle: given a subgoal, how to create the right auxiliary lemma

Tags: isabelle

I have defined a labeled transition system, and the function which accpets the list that system could reach. For convinence, I defined another funtion used for collecting reachable states. And I want to prove the relation between these two functions.

```
type_synonym ('q,'a) LTS = "('q * 'a set * 'q) set"

primrec LTS_is_reachable :: "('q, 'a) LTS \<Rightarrow> 'q \<Rightarrow> 'a list \<Rightarrow> 'q \<Rightarrow> bool" where
   "LTS_is_reachable \<Delta> q [] q' = (q = q')"|
   "LTS_is_reachable \<Delta> q (a # w) q' =
      (\<exists>q'' \<sigma>. a \<in> \<sigma> \<and> (q, \<sigma>, q'') \<in> \<Delta> \<and> LTS_is_reachable \<Delta> q'' w q')"


primrec LTS_is_reachable_set :: "('q, 'a) LTS ⇒ 'q ⇒ 'a list ⇒ 'q set" where    
  "LTS_is_reachable_set Δ q [] = {q}"|
  "LTS_is_reachable_set Δ q (a # w) = \<Union> ((λ(q, σ, q''). if a \<in> σ then LTS_is_reachable_set Δ q'' w else {}) ` Δ)"

lemma "LTS_is_reachable Δ q1 w q2 \<Longrightarrow> q2\<in>(LTS_is_reachable_set Δ  q1 w)"
  apply (induct w)
   apply simp
```

Have such a lemma, I don't know how to prove it.

The subgoal is here:

```
 ⋀a w. (LTS_is_reachable Δ q1 w q2 ⟹ q2 ∈ LTS_is_reachable_set Δ q1 w) ⟹
           ∃q'' σ. a ∈ σ ∧ (q1, σ, q'') ∈ Δ ∧ LTS_is_reachable Δ q'' w q2 ⟹
           ∃x∈Δ. q2 ∈ (case x of (q, σ, q'') ⇒ if a ∈ σ then LTS_is_reachable_set Δ q'' w else {})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your example beyond how to prove the lemma: Your definition of `LTS_is_reachable_set` is buggy. Consider the second equation of this definition:

```
"LTS_is_reachable_set Δ q (a # w) = ⋃ ((λ(q, σ, q''). ...
```

The issue here is that variable `q` in `λ(q, σ, q'')` is *not* the same as the parameter `q` in the left-hand side. Therefore, you should rename `q` in the right-hand side to, for example, `q'` and explicitly check that `q` and `q'` are equal as follows:

```
"LTS_is_reachable_set Δ q (a # w) = ⋃ ((λ(q', σ, q''). if a ∈ σ ∧ q' = q then ...
```

Now, you can prove your lemma by induction on `w` as you intended to do it. However, you need to weaken the induction hypotheses by making `q1` an arbitrary value so you can effectively apply it in your proof. Here's an example of how you  can prove your lemma:

```
lemma "LTS_is_reachable Δ q1 w q2 ⟹ q2 ∈ LTS_is_reachable_set Δ q1 w"
proof (induction w arbitrary: q1)
  case Nil
  then show ?case
    by simp
next
  case (Cons a w)
  from `LTS_is_reachable Δ q1 (a # w) q2`
  obtain q'' and σ
  where "a ∈ σ" and "(q1, σ, q'') ∈ Δ" and "LTS_is_reachable Δ q'' w q2"
    by auto
  moreover from `LTS_is_reachable Δ q'' w q2` and Cons.IH
  have "q2 ∈ LTS_is_reachable_set Δ q'' w"
    by simp
  ultimately show ?case
    by fastforce
qed
```

Comment: One remark: For the sake of clarity, you can use the syntax `⋃ x ∈ A. f` instead of ``⋃ ((λx. f) ` A)``.